# is it possible to generate a set of template classes by using another template and recursion?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I want to create a few template classes in order to assert certain type of data:

```
assertType { static constexpr bool v{false}; };
template<> struct assertType<int> { static constexpr bool v{true}; };
template<> struct assertType<bool> { static constexpr bool v{true}; };
template<>struct assertType<float> { static constexpr bool v{true}; };
template<>struct assertType<long> { static constexpr bool v{true}; };
```

However, I would like to do it programmatically, So I thought about defining a "list" of the supported types:

```
template<typename ...Types>
struct TypesList { };
static inline TypesList<int, bool, float, long> supportedTypes;
```

And have that "list" passed to another template that, by recursion, generates the "assertType" template for every type in the list. Something like:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
struct BuildTemplates { };

template<typename ...Ts>
struct BuildTemplates<TypesList<Ts...>> { };

BuildTemplates<supportedTypes> /* Build the templates for int, bool, float and long */
```

So I can use:

```
assertType<int>::v // v should be true
assertType<bool>::v // v should be true
assertType<float>::v // v should be true
assertType<long>::v // v should be true
```

Any other template whose type is not one of those, should have its v value set to false.

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it acceptable for the "programmatic" solution to define a single template specialization of `assertType`, or to otherwise appear within the class template definition of it?

Comment: It is unclear what purpose `TypeList` serves, that wouldn't be served simply by invoking `BuildTemplates<int, bool, float, long>`. That's just one of the things that's unclear about this question, which seems like an XY problem. Can you explain the real problem you're trying to solve, not the question you're asking here, but the real problem to which you believe the answer is to concoct templates and classes that work like this, so that's what you're asking. Perhaps if the real problem is described, a much simpler answer will exist.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik As you said, the purpose would be filled by invoking the template constructor like: BuildTemplates<int, bool, float, long>, however, I wanted to do it this way only for the sake of learning more on this topic

Comment: The best way to "learning more" on any C++ "topic" is using an organized, methodical curriculum from a good C++ textbook. Attempting to implement random programs, using random techniques, is not going to be very productive. And you've already shown how to do that, using specialization, so now it's completely unclear what the real question is, here.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts. I only need to generate the required templates. Not only one of the specializations, but all of the mentioned.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. I think the question is quite clear and you already showed to have understand it in the first place. I just want a way to build the required templates. You wrote "that wouldn't be served simply by invoking BuildTemplates<int, bool, float, long>" so that means you understood the problem quite well. The need for BuildTemplates<supportedTypes> over BuildTemplates<int, bool, float, long> is just for particular reason that need not be mentioned. I'm not asking how to pass TypesList as an argument, I've it very clear and have worked in the past with that. the question is different

Comment: Be cautious, Juan. A question is always clear to the asker. They aren't doing the answering, though.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly: have `BuildTemplates` define a `constexpr` method, with its own template parameter, that returns `true` if the template type matches any one of `BuildTemplates`'s one. Then, a `typedef` for an instance of `BuildTemplates`, and a free-standing `assertType` template is just an alias definition, that uses the `typedef` alias. But, I have a feeling that there's some other requirement that hasn't been made clear...

Comment: This is basically a `contains<TypeList, T>` metafunction: `assertType<int>::v` is just `contains<SupportedTypes, int>::value`, which is [trivial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_containsl_v).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "*It is unclear what purpose `TypeList` serves*" It's a "type list". It's a list of types. It's a type that exists to support handing someone a single thing that represents a list of types which that someone can process and manipulate. This is a pretty standard metaprogramming tool, and you not knowing about it is not cause to suggest the question is illegitimate. And FYI: most books on C++ metaprogramming are horribly out of date, as it has changed substantially from C++03 to C++20.

Answer (score 6):

The answer mostly depends on the syntax you want to get. For example, you could do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Types> struct TypeList {};

using SupportedTypes = TypeList<int, bool, float, long>;

template<typename T>
struct assertType {
    template<class... Types>
    static constexpr bool contains(TypeList<Types...>) {
        return (std::is_same_v<T, Types> || ...);
    }

    static constexpr bool v = contains(SupportedTypes{});
};

static_assert( assertType<int>::v);
static_assert( assertType<bool>::v);
static_assert(!assertType<short>::v);
```

If you can use `boost`, [`boost::mp11::mp_contains`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_containsl_v) could be employed to make the implementation trivial:

```
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>

using SupportedTypes = boost::mp11::mp_list<int, bool, float, long>;

template<typename T>
struct assertType : boost::mp11::mp_contains<SupportedTypes, T> {};

static_assert( assertType<int>::value);
static_assert( assertType<bool>::value);
static_assert(!assertType<short>::value);
```

Or if you want to use `v` instead of `value` (which is de facto a standard name):

```
template<typename T>
struct assertType {
    static constexpr bool v =
        boost::mp11::mp_contains<SupportedTypes, T>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if your programmatic solution is allowed to define a template specialization of `assertType`, or to be used within its template definition.

Here's an approach by defining a single [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) of `assertType` in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

```cpp
template <typename>
struct assertType { static constexpr bool v = false; };

template <typename...>
struct TypeList {};

using supportedTypes = TypesList<int, bool, float, long>;

#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
struct any_of : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Us>
struct any_of<T, TypeList<U, Us...>> : any_of<T, TypeList<Us...>> {};

template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct any_of<T, TypeList<T, Us...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct assertType<typename std::enable_if<any_of<T, supportedTypes>, T>::type> {
  static constexpr bool v = true;
};
```

You could also just use it within the class template definition itself rather than defining a partial specialization:

```cpp
// assuming supportedTypes and any_of have already been defined

template <typename T>
struct assertType { static constexpr bool v = any_of<T, supportedTypes>::value; };
```

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) the definition of `any_of` becomes much simpler with a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and [`std::bool_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
struct any_of : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct any_of<T, TypeList<Us...>> : std::bool_constant<(... || std::is_same_v<T, Us>)> {};
```

Or by using [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
struct any_of : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct any_of<T, TypeList<Us...>> : std::disjunction<std::is_same_v<T, Us>...> {};
```

Finally in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), you can simplify the definition of the `assertType` partial template specialization using [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```cpp
// assuming supportedTypes and any_of have already been defined

template <typename T, typename L>
concept any_of_v = any_of<T, L>::value;

template <typename>
struct assertType { static constexpr bool v = false; };

template <any_of_v<supportedTypes> T>
struct assertType<T> { static constexpr bool v = true; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for instantiating a template or preprocessor trickery, there is no way to generate declarations in C++ automatically. Each declaration must be written out explicitly.

But there is no need to have an explicit specialization for each type in the list. You can simply use a single primary template for `assertType` and set the `v` member according to membership in the list or you can use a fixed number of partial specializations. The other answers give approaches to do this.